# backdrop does not cover the navigation bar for react-native-modalbox

Tags: react-native

I am refering [react-native-modalbox](https://github.com/maxs15/react-native-modalbox) to present view modally in react native. 
This component works great until I use it inside the Navigator. But If this component is used inside the Navigator Component, then the model presented does not cover the navigation bar, where as the alert does cover it.

```
render: function() {
var modalView =

  <Button onPress={this.openModal3} style={styles.btn}>Position centered + backdrop + disable</Button>

  <Modal style={[styles.modal, styles.modal3]} position={"center"} ref={"modal3"} isDisabled={this.state.isDisabled}>
    <Text style={styles.text}>Modal centered</Text>
    <Button onPress={this.toggleDisable} style={styles.btn}>Disable ({this.state.isDisabled ? "true" : "false"})</Button>
  </Modal>

</View>
return (
  <NavigatorIOS style ={{flex:1}}
  ref={'nav'}

  initialRoute={{
    component: ()=> modalView,
    title:'Photoos.Net',
    passProps:{ name: this.props.title},

  }}/>
); 
}
});
```

Refer to following screens for my issue.
[image]

Is there way to make this model behave exactly like alert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the modal is defined as a child of the navigator. React native doesn't support zindex but yields that type of behavior based on the rendering order. Some useful links on this topic:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1076

Similar question asked in the react-native-modalbox project: https://github.com/maxs15/react-native-modalbox/issues/60

Here's an example using a stripped down version of your code snippet to demonstrate how rendering order works. When you tap "OPEN" the modal will open over top of the Navigator:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  NavigatorIOS,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableHighlight,
  View
} from 'react-native';

import Modal from 'react-native-modalbox';

class MyApp2 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.openModal3 = this.openModal3.bind(this);
  }

  openModal3() {
    this.refs.modal3.open();
  }

  render() {
    var modalView = <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.openModal3}>
        <Text>OPEN</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>;

    return (
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <NavigatorIOS
          style ={{flex:1}}
          ref={'nav'}
          initialRoute={{
            component: ()=> modalView,
            title:'Photoos.Net'
          }}/>

        <Modal style={[styles.container, styles.modal]} position={"center"} ref={"modal3"}>
          <Text>Modal centered</Text>
        </Modal>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#f00'
  },

  modal: {
    backgroundColor: '#0f0'
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp2', () => MyApp2);
```

Comment: Yes that's true.  Even I also figure out same solution. Thanks man

Answer (score 4):

The `Modal` component from `react-native-modalbox` accepts a `coverScreen` property like so:

```
<Modal coverScreen={true} ...
```